# Why new two node cluster not behaving right?

Tags: linux, failovercluster, pacemaker, corosync

I’m trying to create cluster of two nodes, but it seems to behave a little strange following this [guide](http://clusterlabs.org/quickstart-redhat-6.html), but I was unable to do, for example:

```
[root@afnA ~]# pcs property set stonith-enabled=false
Error: Unable to update cib
Call cib_replace failed (-62): Timer expired
```

only thing I find in logs are continued `corosync` events:

```
Nov 06 01:30:54 corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List: 96 97 
Nov 06 01:30:56 corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List: 96 97 
Nov 06 01:30:57 corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List: 96 97 
Nov 06 01:30:59 corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List: 96 97 
Nov 06 01:31:01 corosync [TOTEM ] Retransmit List: 96 97 
...
```

Let me known if more info would help!

[pcs cluster report](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13225502/pacemaker.report.tar.bz2)

```
CentOS 6.7 w/:
pacemaker-1.1.12-8.el6.x86_64
pcs-0.9.139-9.el6_7.1.x86_64
ccs-0.16.2-81.el6.x86_64
resource-agents-3.9.5-24.el6.x86_64
cman-3.0.12.1-73.el6.1.x86_64
corosync-1.4.7-2.el6.x86_64

[root@afnB ~]# pacemakerd --features
Pacemaker 1.1.11 (Build: 97629de) Supporting v3.0.9: generated-manpages agent-manpages ascii-docs ncurses libqb-logging libqb-ipc nagios corosync-plugin cman acls

[root@afnB ~]# corosync-quorumtool -l
Nodeid     Name
   1   afnA.mxi.tdcfoo
   2   afnB.mxi.tdcfoo
[root@afnB ~]# corosync-quorumtool -s
Version:          1.4.7
Nodes:            2
Ring ID:          8
Quorum type:      quorum_cman
Quorate:          Yes
[root@afnB ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: afn-cluster
WARNING: no stonith devices and stonith-enabled is not false
Last updated: Fri Nov  6 01:35:30 2015
Last change: Fri Nov  6 01:29:37 2015
Stack: cman
Current DC: afna - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.11-97629de
2 Nodes configured
0 Resources configured

Online: [ afna afnb ]

Full list of resources:
```

[root@afnB ~]# cat /etc/cluster/cluster.conf

```
<cluster config_version="1" name="afn-cluster">
  <fence_daemon/>
  <clusternodes>
    <clusternode name="afna" nodeid="1">
      <fence>
        <method name="pcmk-redirect">
          <device name="pcmk" port="afna"/>
        </method>
      </fence>
    </clusternode>
    <clusternode name="afnb" nodeid="2">
      <fence>
        <method name="pcmk-redirect">
          <device name="pcmk" port="afnb"/>
        </method>
      </fence>
    </clusternode>
  </clusternodes>
  <cman/>
  <fencedevices>
    <fencedevice agent="fence_pcmk" name="pcmk"/>
  </fencedevices>
  <rm>
    <failoverdomains/>
    <resources/>
  </rm>
</cluster>
```

[root@afnB ~]# grep -v '#' /etc/corosync/corosync.conf

```
compatibility: whitetank

totem {
        version: 2

        secauth: off
        threads: 0

        window_size: 150

        interface {
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: 10.45.69.0
                mcastaddr: 239.255.15.1
                mcastport: 5405
                ttl: 1
        }
}

logging {
        fileline: off
        to_stderr: no
        to_logfile: yes
        logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
        to_syslog: yes
        debug: off
        timestamp: on
        logger_subsys {
                subsys: AMF
                debug: off
        }
}
```

Comment: Firewalling.  It's always firewalling.  (disclaimer: may not *always* be firewalling)

Comment: Nope have no FW between nodes :)

Comment: Seem unicast fixed the issue ;)
This was done by changing cman configuration to udpu transport in cluster.conf like this:

 ***<cman transport="udpu" port="5405" two_node="1" expected_votes="1” />***

Assuming multicast in open vswitch is the culprit as multicasting stopped after 180s f.ex. with omping, also see [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=42250)